# MUI - Autocomplete color styles broken

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For some unknow reason the font color of the Autocomplete list is white, the only css property that I have added in the body is `background-color: "#fafbff"`, but I have tested already and this is not the cause of the issue

[image: bug]

```
export default function FreeSolo() {
  return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="freeSolo" />}
      />
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        disableClearable
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Search input"
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              type: "search",
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

I am also using a component with the following style `li { font-color: white }`

Comment: Nothing's wrong in your code. You must have the color set to white somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you helped find the issue, I had a component with a global li style set to white

Comment: So... it seems that the autocomplete list is wrapped in the li tag

Comment: Feel free to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-7703p?file=/demo.js) and there is nothing wrong with it. It's possible that you have the color set to `white` from somewhere else, so please check it. You can confirm your code is working by putting the code snippet in your question in a new project.